# Change GWT Servlet Mapping at Compile Time

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, annotations

I'm working on updating a legacy project that uses GWT RPC for server communication. The original project used ant task in the build script to replace a placeholder with the version number of the project. I'm assuming the idea was to allow the version number to be updated in a single place rather than having to manually find/replace it everywhere. The problem I'm running into is that that process won't work if I want to use @RemoteServiceRelativePath to link my services to the client. I can modify the web.xml with the build script, but I don't know how to update the annotations in my code to match. I'm aware that it is possible to modify the ServiceDef at runtime with 'setServiceEntryPoint' but I would like to avoid that mess if possible.

As an example, if my web.xml looks like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>authBackendImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproj.server.servlet.MyAuthBackendImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>authBackendImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mymodule/@version/authBackend</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I could use a replace task in the ant build to swap the @version with the actual number. The problem is in my service interface:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath(value = "@version/authBackend")
public interface MyAuthBackend extends RemoteService {

}
```

Is there some way to have a variable definition for the annotation value? Or is there some other solution I'm just not seeing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you replace the code in the .java file the same way you do it in the web.xml?  If you've moved to Maven there is a filtering capability but ant  is very easy to manage it with too.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way, I guess, It can by done, is to set up end point each time, you are going to connect to service.
Of course you can beautify the code yourself by wrapping it to some factory class, but in the simple manner it should looks like below:

```
AuthBackendImpl authService = GWT.create(AuthBackend.class);
((ServiceDefTarget) authService).setServiceEntryPoint(String.format("/yourprojectname-SNAPSHOT/mymodule/%s/authBackend",version));
```